# What date format is this and how do I convert it into a MM-DD-YYYY format and vice versa

Tags: date, datetime, sms

I've been handed a whole file of sms messages from a guy's phone, who is trying to do something like whatsapp. These messages were exported from his cell phone, and have the date as `1410440383791`. Can anyone figure out what format this date stamp is in, and how I can convert it into a regular MM-DD-YYYY format and also vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is possible that it is unix time (number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970)? If so, that date converts to 9/11/2014, 8:59:43 AM GMT

[Converter Used](http://www.epochconverter.com/)

Comment: You're kinda correct. That's the same date it shows in the column next to it, but with a few hours difference `Sep 11, 2014 6:29:43 PM`.

Comment: Its likely because of the timezone you are in.  Unix time is in the GMT Timezone